# How to stop NSCollectioView's selectionIndexes from notifying on both mouseDown and mouseUp

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing, nscollectionview

I'm observing the 'selectionIndexes' of an NSCollectionView instance like so:

```
[self.collectionView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectionIndexes" options:0 context:nil];
```

Then I'm responding to the changes in observeValueForKeyPath: like so:

```
if(object == self.collectionView)
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"selectionIndexes"])
        NSLog(@"selectionIndexes CHANGED");
}
```

I'm noticing that if I click on an item I get two notifications, one for the mouse down event, and again for the mouse up event. Both times the selectionIndexes property is returning the item's index. You can even do the click slowly, down-pause-up and watch the two distinct firings in the logs.

This doesn't seem normal, how do I stop this? Is there a better way to be notified when an NSCollectionItem is clicked?

UPDATE:
I discovered it is fired twice because I was also clearing the selection in observeValueForKeyPath:

```
if(object == self.collectionView)
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"selectionIndexes"])
    {
        NSLog(@"selectionIndexes CHANGED");
        [self.collectionView setSelectionIndexes:nil];
    }
}
```

For some reason NSCollectionView sees that it's selection is set to nil in the mouse up event from the item, and it resets the selection indexes. Still not sure how I want to get around this because I do need to set the selection back to zero.

Answer (score 0):

To set an empty selection, set `selectionIndexes` to an empty `NSIndexSet` like this:

```
[self.collectionView setSelectionIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSet]];
```